# SQL Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code that I need to translate from Oracle to SQL Server and I'm getting this error message:

> "MMsg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 23 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

This is also connecting to another SQL Server.  It is pulling data from one SQL Server and adding it to another SQL Server.

The code is below.

```
--Import Parcel
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS VISION_PARCEL;
SELECT * 
INTO [dbo].[VISION_PARCEL]
FROM [TOMSQLVISION].[VISION_2020].[REAL_PROP].[PARCEL]
```

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` is not supported by SQL Server.  Square braces are not supported by most other databases.  The code doesn't look right.

Comment: The `IF EXISTS` clause of drop table requires SQL Server 2016 or later.

Answer (score 0):

*(Assuming that your code is on SQL Server)*
To check whether table exists before `Select Into`, use the following

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.VISION_PARCEL', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
Begin
    DROP TABLE dbo.VISION_PARCEL; 
End
```

Then Execute

```
SELECT * 
INTO [dbo].[VISION_PARCEL]
FROM [TOMSQLVISION].[VISION_2020].[REAL_PROP].[PARCEL]
```